# prepositions "de" vs "sobre"

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

I was chatting with a friend I wanted to say that I was about to do some exercises and I said "voy a hacer algunos ejercicios de conjunciones básicas".

I was wondering that in this case, should I use "sobre conjunciones"?

Comment: Both are ok. You can use either. Same as in English when sometimes you can use _on_ or _about_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositions are tricky but in this case both are ok and you can use either.

Same as in English when sometimes you can use *on* or *about* i.e:

> It is very entertaining for a book **on** mathematics / Es entretenido para ser un libro **de** matemáticas
>
> It is very entertaining for a book **about** mathematics / Es entretenido para ser un libro **sobre** matemáticas